# "error while loading user profile metadata" with WSO2 API Manager 4.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have added an Active Directory to the carbon console to connect to WSO2 API Manager , i have successfully read the users list but when i try to get the informations of each user i got error `error while loading user profile metadata` .

[image: Image de ma configuration]

Comment: Can you post the full error you are getting?

Comment: [2023-02-06 14:58:29,944] ERROR - AbstractUserStoreManager org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while getting LDAP role names. SearchBase: ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org ConstructedFilter: (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=*))